# Why is MenuCommandKey not working in my stylesheet?

Tags: front-end

Here is the cell style data for my custom version of Section:

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 MenuCommandKey->"1",
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 CellFrame->{{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CellMargins->{{10, Inherited}, {8, Inherited}},
 CellFrameMargins->1]
```

But when I type command+1 I still get the old red Title cell.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll also need to make a version of the Title cell which has the `MenuCommandKey` option unset.  I.e.,

```
Cell[StyleData["Title"], MenuCommandKey->None]
```

The FE doesn't have a standard way of resolving styles with overlapping `MenuCommandKey` options, so if you want it to work properly, it's important to make sure that you prevent overlaps.